# What is Pind Deh? Does it attach to Soul and transmigrate to next life, imparting karmas etc?

Tags: atma, rebirth

What is Pind Deh? Does it attach to Soul and transmigrate to next life, imparting karmas etc? Karma, influence of previous birth, reincarnation.